# Is there a way to deserialize properties which have special charaters in names with ElasticLowLevelClient.SearchAsync?

Tags: elasticsearch-net

I have logstash pushing logs into elasticsearch which automatically inserts the `@timestamp` field into each doc. I used `Elasticsearch.Net` instead of `NEST` in this project.

Each doc looks something like:

```
{
  "Origin": 0,
  "VisitorId": "49f843eb-be38-4912-a3b8-277841cd709d",
  "CompanyId": 1,
  "ActivityType": 21,
  "Referer": "http://cn.bing.com/search?q=sogou&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IE10SR",
  "ProductId": 1,
  "version": "1.0",
  "Url": "http://localhost:8001/Product/Detail/1",
  "DeviceType": 1,
  "@timestamp": "2017-03-21T02:04:13.136Z",
  "UserId": 4,
  "host": "ZBL-PC",
  "@version": "1",
  "IpAddress": "14.197.145.136",
  "timestamp": "2017-03-21T02:04:13.136Z"
}
```

Currently, my search query looks like:

```
var res = client.SearchAsync<SearchResult<ProductVisit>>(index: _indexName,
    type: "viewsingleproduct",
    body: new PostData<object>(new
    {
      size = 10
    }));

public class ProductVisit
{
  public int? UserId { get; set; }
  public Guid? VisitorId { get; set; }
  public int DeviceType { get; set; }
  public string timestamp { get; set; }
  public int CompanyId { get; set; }
  public long ProductId { get; set; }
}

public class Hit<TDocument>
{
  public TDocument _source { get; set; }
}

public class Hits<TDocument>
{
  public int total { get; set; }
  public List<Hit<TDocument>> hits { get; set; }
}

public class SearchResult<TDocument>
{
  public Hits<TDocument> hits { get; set; }
}
```

The `Elasticsearch.Net` way of retrieving docs is to declare a DTO which can be automatically deserialized into from the json in the response. However, in this case, I cannot declare a property that is a valid C# property name such that `@timestamp` values can be filled into.

In `Nest` which uses Newtonsoft.json, I can specify the actual field name in elasticsearch by attribute annotations (I remember `JsonProperty` will do the trick and also NEST has its own attribute that lets you specify the property name). However, `Elasticsearch.Net` doesn't use Newtonsoft.json internally. It uses `SimpleJson` which could've supported similar tricks via `DataMember` attribute but it requires `SIMPLE_JSON_DATACONTRACT` preprocessor switch to be enabled and `Elasticsearch.Net` disabled it by default.

Currently my solution is to copy `@timestamp` field into `timestamp` in logstash config, as shown in the json doc above. But it is a hack.

---

I originally had problems in the request side where official examples mostly construct queries using anonymous types like this:

```
new
{
  term = new
  {
    _TopicPostId = new {
      value = 4
    }
  }
},
```

But occasionally I need to construct queries with field names containing special characters. I finally figured out I could use Dictionary instead of anonymous types and it worked. For example:

```
new {
  range = new Dictionary<string, object>{{
    "@timestamp",
    new
    {
      gte = "now-1d/d",
      lte = "now/d"
    }
  }}
},
```

Comment: is there a reason for preferring Elasticsearch.Net instead of using NEST?

Comment: With NEST, I like the strongly typed approach for index creation, mapping, indexing documents and search queries. In my case, the former three points are taken care of by logstash. For the last point, I liked how Elasticsearch.Net allowed me to adjust my queries by just adjusting DTOs and anonymous objects.

Comment: @RussCam see my other comment. No strong reasons. I just view it as a dynamically typed query and NEST as a statically typed one. Is NEST always preferred?

Comment: Just curious to understand if there were any strong technical reasons why NEST wouldn't be preferred :) With Elasticsearch.Net, you can implement your own `IElasticsearchSerializer` using JSON.Net to overcome field names with special characters or alternatively, you may consider using NEST and the low level client exposed on the high level client via the `.LowLevel` property; this way, the low level client will use JSON.Net for serialization too

Comment: @RussCam Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. I'd probably use NEST's LowLevel client to avoid the hassle of implementing `IElasticsearchSerializer`.